# Issue during first commit of web project from eclipse to github repository

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I am trying to upload (or perform initial commit) of my existing web project into github repository.

Below are the steps followed.

1. Right click on project -> Team -> Share Project
2. Configure git repository -> Create the directory structure in local system

Example - 
D:\Others\Projects\My Work\Git\AdoreIndiaRepo.git

Initially the project is displayed as - Adore_india [AdoreIndiaRepo NO-HEAD]

3. Right click on project -> Team -> Commit

Git staging perspective is opened. All the files of the project are displayed as Unstaged Changes

4. Select all unstaged changes -> Add to Index

All the files of the project are displayed as Staged Changes.

5. Provide commit message and click Commit and Push button
6. Destination git repository -> Remote name (origin) -> Remote git repository details are provided -> Next
7. [Push branch master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjTW9.jpg)
8. After clicking Finish button, error is displayed as :

master -> master [rejected - non-fast-forward]

I have even tried uploading using gib bash. But the same error is thrown. Please mention if any other details are required.

Comment: Are you certain that you are really the first one to push to this branch/repository?  The error message you got usually means something else.

Comment: Initially after creating github account, I had uploaded a sample file using drag and drop feature. The file has been deleted. Is this the cause? If yes how do I resolve it?

Comment: Can you try this: `git push --force origin master`?  This would overwrite whatever is there, regardless of any conflicts.  Only do this is you don't care about what is the on the remote `master` branch, which from you what you seemed to suspect should be nothing at all.

Comment: Excellent. This works without any issues and the project is uploaded in repository. However I am not sure why the conflict was showing as there was no existing files in the repository. Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I am not sure why the conflict was showing as there was no existing files in the repository.

Because there was a conflicting history:

- GitHub has one or two commits (because of the uploaded -- then deleted -- file)
- your local repo has one commit (the initial one)

That is:

```
 x--x (origin/master)

 x    (master)
```

Force pushing replace the GitHub history with your own.